# Директива Angular мешает "родиться" DOM элементу

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-directive

Есть небольшая директива, которая должна, при нажатии на элемент с ней, открыть этот элемент на фулл скрин. Но на практике элемент с директивой просто не появляется в DOM дереве.
Код самой директивы:

```
  selector: '[openfullscreen]',
})
export class OpenFullscreenDirective<T>   {

  private _element: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this._element = this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
  }

  @Input()
  set openfullscreen(el: HTMLElement) {
    this._element = el;
  }

  @HostListener('click')
  openFullscreen(): void {
    console.log(this._element);
    this._element.requestFullscreen();
  }

}
```

Код шаблона:

```
   <div #wrapper class="wrapper">
     <div class="camera-data-container">
       <div *openfullscreen="wrapper" class="icon-full-screen">
```

Comment: ты уверен, что тебе действительно нужна [структурная директива](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)?

Comment: Как выше написал @Grundy, здесь не требуется структурная директива, т.к. мы никак не взаимодействуем с структурой разметки.
Напишите ```<div [openfullscreen]="wrapper" class="icon-full-screen">```